# probablity question related to 2 die and the classic monopoly game.

Tags: probability, dice

While playing [monopoly](http://www.old-games.com/screenshot/3211-5-monopoly-deluxe.jpg) I accidentally figured out that probability for landing on `Illionis Avenue` is most in the whole game and for landing on orange colored group is most together.

So, after knowing this now, `I want to know probability for landing on every space separately for a 9X4 board.`

monopoly game-board has `10X4 spaces` but a friend of mine has a similar game with `9X4 spaces`

I know a little of probability but that is not enough for my question to be solved...

Comment: If you want the unconditional probability of landing on a position, that is just 1 divided by the number of positions. The probability you are seeking probably needs some more specification

Comment: No, in fact the asymptotic (that is, long into the game so that the starting point being GO is no longer influencing the probabilities) probabilities are **not** all equal at 1/40. The reasons are that (a) The GO TO JAIL space moves you from square 30 to square 10 "magically, effectively increasing the probabilities on 2nd street and decreasing 4th streat. (Park Place has the lowest probability)> b) The Chance cards move you around; for example, there is an "Advance to Illinois".  This is a solved problem of finding the eigenvalues of the transition matrix. I thought Penn. RR was most common..

Comment: @MarkFischler Good point. I will let my comment remain in case someone  will be tempted to make the same mistake.

Comment: I suppose you include the "going to jail" option, since this is a feature of the board itself. Do you also include all the Chance Cards and their effects that Mark Fischler mentions? If you do, simulating a million games is probably the easiest way of finding the probabilities.

Comment: @ HowDoIMath i know a little c++ programming, i could do that.